# How to trigger ListView refresh from other items in the list

Tags: listview, flutter

I have searched the archives and have found several questions on this topic, but none of the issues exactly match my problem. I have a list of players in a ListView that also includes an IconButton, a string name, and a checkbox. I want to mimic a Radio Button behavior (i.e. a mutually exclusive property where only one button can be selected, pressing one turns any other selected "button" off). The "Radio Button" is meant to indicate who is the 'Captain' of the team. There can be only one Captain in the group. The default screen will show the first player as selected, pressing another row will highlight that selection, however, the first name will not "unselect". Pressing the checkbox for the 1st name will unhighlight that row as well as "pulling the list down" and using the RefreshIndicator. But simply pressing the Icon button has no effect on the other rows.

I have seen several topics on adding items to the list and automatically refreshing the ListView, but I cannot find any information on updating other items in the list when an onPressed function is activated from a different row. I have tried adding didChangeDependencies thinking that might update the other listView items but I can't get that to work either.

Is there some setting that I'm missing that would allow for this functionality?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Group group;

class Player {
  String name;
  bool captain;
  bool press;

  Player({this.captain, this.name, this.press});
}

class Group {
  List<Player> players = [];

  void addNewPlayer(String name, bool banker, bool pressing) {
    final player = Player(name: name, captain: banker, press: pressing);
    players.add(player);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Players'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    group = Group();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      group.addNewPlayer('Player $i', i == 1, false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        child: ListLayout(),
        onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Null> _handleRefresh() async {
    setState(() {
      ListLayout();
    });

    return null;
  }
}

class PlayerCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int curPlayer;
  final Group group;

  PlayerCard({Key key, this.group, this.curPlayer}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayerCardState createState() => _PlayerCardState();
}

class _PlayerCardState extends State<PlayerCard> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    setState(() {
      ListLayout();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var group = widget.group;
    var curPlayer = widget.curPlayer;

    return Container(
      child: Card(
        color:
            group.players[curPlayer].captain ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.adjust),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  for (int i = 0; i < group.players.length; i++) {
                    group.players[i].captain = (i == widget.curPlayer);
                  }

                  didChangeDependencies();
                });
              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    group.players[curPlayer].name,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Checkbox(
                value: group.players[curPlayer].press,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      group.players[curPlayer].press = value;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListLayoutState createState() => _ListLayoutState();
}

class _ListLayoutState extends State<ListLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: group.players.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return PlayerCard(
              curPlayer: index, group: group, key: ValueKey(group));
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `setState(() {ListLayout();});` is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can pass `callback` `refresh()` in `_ListLayoutState` to `PlayerCard` 
and in `PlayerCard` call `widget.callback()`

code snippet

```
class PlayerCard extends StatefulWidget {
 ...
  final VoidCallback callback;
  PlayerCard({Key key, this.group, this.curPlayer, this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

   ...    
   onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  ...
                  widget.callback();    

class _ListLayoutState extends State<ListLayout> {
  void refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }
  ...
  return PlayerCard(
            curPlayer: index,
            group: group,
            key: ValueKey(group),
            callback: refresh,
          );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Group group;

class Player {
  String name;
  bool captain;
  bool press;

  Player({this.captain, this.name, this.press});
}

class Group {
  List<Player> players = [];

  void addNewPlayer(String name, bool banker, bool pressing) {
    final player = Player(name: name, captain: banker, press: pressing);
    players.add(player);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Players'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    group = Group();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      group.addNewPlayer('Player $i', i == 1, false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        child: ListLayout(),
        onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Null> _handleRefresh() async {
    setState(() {
      ListLayout();
    });

    return null;
  }
}

class PlayerCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int curPlayer;
  final Group group;
  final VoidCallback callback;
  PlayerCard({Key key, this.group, this.curPlayer, this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayerCardState createState() => _PlayerCardState();
}

class _PlayerCardState extends State<PlayerCard> {
  /*@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    setState(() {
      ListLayout();
    });
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var group = widget.group;
    var curPlayer = widget.curPlayer;

    return Container(
      child: Card(
        color:
            group.players[curPlayer].captain ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.adjust),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  for (int i = 0; i < group.players.length; i++) {
                    group.players[i].captain = (i == widget.curPlayer);
                  }
                  widget.callback();
                  //didChangeDependencies();
                });
              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    group.players[curPlayer].name,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Checkbox(
                value: group.players[curPlayer].press,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      group.players[curPlayer].press = value;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListLayoutState createState() => _ListLayoutState();
}

class _ListLayoutState extends State<ListLayout> {
  void refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: group.players.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return PlayerCard(
            curPlayer: index,
            group: group,
            key: ValueKey(group),
            callback: refresh,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: That works great and it is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.